# My test cases are passing succefully but build failed due to 0-SNAPSHOT.jar is not inside on jenkins maven project

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea, testng

My job results are following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8zP5.png)

Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I have spent some time on that and figured out that my path is right, but I have added the path in the wrong fields. Here is the right way to add the path to the root POM.xml:

1. Under Build in Root POM field mention only "pom.xml" and
2. Below the "Goals and options" field click on advanced and
3. Then click on "Use custom workspace" and here mention the path of your project directory("/Users/mac/Downloads/BaseProjectForJenkins").

So When the job runs on the Jenkins it'll take the path to the POM.xml and the issue will be fixed.[My build configurations file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JogP6.png)

Click on the link to open the attached file.